# Wrong value being assign to a variable.. Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

i currently working on a project using xamarin on visual studio 2015(C#).
In debugging process i've noticed some weird behaviour. The variable that bind with a button has been assigned a wrong value than it should be when the button being clicked.

```
int choose;
    int chooseBuff = 0;
    private int clickCounter = 0;
    private int clickBuffer = 0;
    private int timerInterval = 1000;
    Timer timer;
    Button btnRed, btnBlue, btnYellow;
    Vibrator vibrate;
    List<int> patternList = new List<int>();
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        vibrate = (Vibrator)GetSystemService(Context.VibratorService);
        btnRed = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnRed);
        btnBlue = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnBlue);
        btnYellow = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnYellow);

        //AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        //alert.SetTitle("");
        //alert.SetMessage("You Lose!!");
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = timerInterval;
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();

        btnRed.Click += BtnRed_Click;
        btnBlue.Click += BtnBlue_Click;
        btnYellow.Click += BtnYellow_Click;

    }

    private void BtnYellow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        vibrate.Vibrate(100);
        clickBuffer = 3;
        checkClick();
        intervalIncrease();
    }
    private void BtnBlue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        vibrate.Vibrate(100);
        clickBuffer = 2;
        checkClick();
        intervalIncrease();
    }
    private void BtnRed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        vibrate.Vibrate(100);
        clickBuffer = 1;
        checkClick();
        intervalIncrease();
    }
```

when btnRed being clicked the clickBuffer variable was assigned a value 3 instead of 1.Same goes for other button. bntBlue will assing value 2 to clickBuffer and bntYellow will assign value 1 to clickBuffer. I don't know where this value come from. Even if i assign other value than thoose 3 like clickBuffer = 5 or even "string" it still assigned value 3 for btnRed. I'm really confused.. Can someone point out what's wrong with my code??

Here the whole project if its helping [LightGame](http://www.mediafire.com/file/a3s1d616bwvfzu1/LightGame.rar). I just started learn to program 2 month ago, so make sure your are ready to look at my ugly code. Its really messy in there. Just write the code to get thing done. Pretty sure it has better solution for it.. Cheers :)..

Comment: I tested it and it working fine, i take value `clickBuffer` as i set in clicked button handler.

Comment: Really?? Its bugging me for 2 days already.. is it posible that my vs is the problem?? But i already restarted it a few times...

Comment: Try clear cache and unnistal app from device, clean solution and debug again.

Comment: Will try that as soon i get back.. but i pretty sure i cleaned solution every times i want to run the code.. is there any other posibilities?

Comment: Make sure you didn't just name your buttons backward.  I can't tell you how many times an error has cropped up for me like this just because I accidentally mislabeled my controls.  What you think is btnRed might be labeled btnYellow.

Comment: Its works!!..i uninstall the app on the device and its work.. yeah i made the mislabeled mistake once and corrected it. But the app still wrong.. maybe the code not updated in the device.. Thanks Wiśnicki for pointing me that simple solution.. silly me :p..

Comment: You should learn how to place breakpoints and step through code. You could then have placed breakpoints in each click handler to see which is called when you click a particular button. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx